# onActivityResult in fragment doesn't update ListView

Tags: java, android

I have 2 fragments, the first is a list of the selected items and the second is where I select the items.
In the onActivityResult event of the first fragment I get the information send from the second fragment, I add the information to object(list) and I assign as datasource to my listview, but this information is not displayed:

[SECUENCE OF MY APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGDk.jpg)

```java
///////FRAGMENT 1:////
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        tbllistadoproducto objproducto= new tbllistadoproducto();
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            //if (requestCode==AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE){
            //String datafromC = data.getStringExtra("datafrom C");
            String dataS= data.getStringExtra("PRODUCTO");
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataS);

                objproducto.setCodf(jsonObject.getString("Codf"));
                objproducto.setCodi(jsonObject.getString("Codi"));
                objproducto.setMarca(jsonObject.getString("Marca"));
                objproducto.setDescripcion(jsonObject.getString("Descripcion"));
                objproducto.setUMedida(jsonObject.getString("UMedida"));
                objproducto.setStock(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("Stock")));
                objproducto.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("Precio")));
                objproducto.setMoneda(jsonObject.getString("Moneda"));

                _lstProductos.add(objproducto);
                adapter_listaproducto adaptador= new adapter_listaproducto(getActivity(),_lstProductos);
                lvwProductos.setAdapter(adaptador);
                //don't DISPLAY THE ITEMS


                //txtTotal.setText("ERRROR");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            finally {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }



            //}
        }

    }

////////////FRAGMENT2 : Code of my Second Fragment to select:///////////////

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listadoproductospedidos, container, false);
        lvwProductos=vista.findViewById(R.id.listadoproductopedido_lvwproductos);
        btnBuscar=vista.findViewById(R.id.listadoproductopedido_imgbtnbuscar);
        txtTexto=vista.findViewById(R.id.listadoproductopedido_txttexto);

        lvwProductos.setClickable(true);
        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CargarProductos();
            }
        });

        lvwProductos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tbllistadoproducto objProducto= (tbllistadoproducto)lvwProductos.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String jsonProducto = gson.toJson(objProducto);
                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                        getTargetRequestCode(),
                        1,
                        new Intent().putExtra("PRODUCTO", jsonProducto)
                );
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
        return vista;
    }
I hope to show the items in my listview, but don't show.
```

Comment: when I set TextView.settext="100.00" in event "onActivityResult" of my first fragment neither has the change

Answer (score 0):

"Adapter name" .notifyDataSetChanged();
 This work will be done on 1st fragment from where your list is not loading

Comment: i get the data correct. but does not update the listview and my Textview when i set to values dont show.

Comment: after getting the data use the above line to update the adapter of the listview -> adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();